# MySQL group replication - cannot connect to remote server

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to setup the group replication plugin I specified all settings in  /etc/mysql/my.cnf and did the appropriate firewall rules: However I cannot connect to the remote server. There are two different public IP address servers and not a local machine.

The ufw output settings on the target server: Iptables is not installed.

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
33061                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere
3306                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere
33061/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
33061 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80,443/tcp (v6)            ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
33061/tcp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Error Log output

```
2018-05-25T17:36:41.825416Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'XCom protocol version: 3'
2018-05-25T17:36:41.825460Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'XCom initialized and ready to accept incoming connections on port 33061'
2018-05-25T17:36:41.912783Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to {remote IP}:33061 on local port: 33061.'
```

If i check the remote port I get:

```
root@li111-4:/etc/nginx/sites-available# nc -zv {remote IP} 33061
nc: connect to {remote IP} port 33061 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```